# Readthedocs autodoc working in pdf but not html

Tags: python, read-the-docs, autodoc

I'm unable to get autodoc to work with ReadTheDocs. Everything works normally locally, and ReadTheDocs shows no errors in raw view.

Moreover pdf version of the docs looks like I intended with functions documented, while html refuses to include the autodoc fragment.

Project page:
https://pygypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Github repo:
https://github.com/RadostW/PyGYPY

I have no idea what to do next.

Comment: Which part of the PDF version do you miss in the HTML? Perhaps you need to refresh the page without browser cache?

Comment: Jesus, I'm such an idiot. Never thought that browser is the issue. Good day to You @a_guest